# DB2 load data copy to S3 as compressed file

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I am trying to load DB2 data into DB2 and saving a copy to S3.

```
db2 load from supplier.tbl of del modified by coldel'|' insert into supplier copy yes to DB2REMOTE://S3/mycontainer/mybucket/loads
```

This creates multiple files (1 for each partitions) by the name `MYDB.4.db2inst1.DBPART001.20190925183423.001`, `MYDB.4.db2inst1.DBPART004.20190925183423.002` and so on and uploads all of them to S3 individually. Is it possible to create a single zip/tar with all these files in a compressed format which can later be downloaded from S3 and uncompressed?

```
[db2inst1@dashmpp-head-0 - Db2wh tpch-dbgen]$ db2level
DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: 
"db2inst1") uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL11019" with level 
identifier "020A010F".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.1.9.0", "special_39004", 
"DYN1906181700AMD64_39004", and Fix Pack "0".
Product is installed at "/opt/ibm/db2/V11.1.0.0".
```

Comment: Why do you need the load copy files; what are you planning to do with them outside the Db2 server?

Answer (score 1):

What Paul Vernon said is right and even suggested as db2 load has become obsolete and slower.

I am not entirely sure about the file part as the documentation says differently.

> **S3**
>
> Specifies that the source data file is located in an S3 compatible object store. The REMOTESOURCE, SWIFT, and S3 options are mutually exclusive. **Use the DATAOBJECT option to specify the file name.**
>
> *Syntax:*
>
> `S3 (endpoint, authKey1, authKey2, bucket)`

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r_create_ext_table.html

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE exttab2(a int) using (
    DATAOBJECT 'datafile2.dat'
    S3 (
        's3.amazonaws.com',
        'XXXOS123456-2:xxx123456',
        'bs07c6e974040737d92174e5e96d5be9382aa4c33xxx5a14eaa9172c70f8df16',
        'my_dev'
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the use case that you want, but you can create a compressed version of the data in a table using an EXTERNAL TABLE statement. E.g. like this

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE 'supplier.gz'  USING
(CCSID 1208 s3(
    's3.amazonaws.com'
,   '<S3-access-key-ID>'
,   '<S3-secret-access-key>'
    '<my_bucket>'
) 
AS SELECT * FROM supplier
```

adding the `PARTITION ALL` into the `USING` will get you one file per data slice, which might not be what you want, but the statement will run faster.  You could also use `COMPRESS LZ4` and you will get a LZ4 compressed file (or files) which again will be faster.